# SQLAlchemy delete association objects

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to batch delete objects from an association table by filtering on a column in one of the relationships. I use the following call in SQLAlchemy to make the delete

```
db.session.query(UserPaper).join(Paper, (UserPaper.paper_id ==
Paper.id)).filter(UserPaper.user_id == user.id).filter(Paper.journal_id 
== journal.id).delete()
```

and it results in the following error

```
OperationalError: (OperationalError) (1054, "Unknown column 'papers.journal_id' 
in 'where clause'") 'DELETE FROM userpapers WHERE userpapers.user_id = %s AND
papers.journal_id = %s' (1L, 1L)
```

Without the delete at the end, the SQLAlchemy query is

```
SELECT userpapers.user_id AS userpapers_user_id, userpapers.paper_id AS 
userpapers_paper_id, userpapers.created AS userpapers_created, 
userpapers.read_at AS userpapers_read_at, userpapers.score AS userpapers_score
FROM userpapers JOIN papers ON userpapers.paper_id = papers.id
WHERE userpapers.user_id = :user_id_1 AND papers.journal_id = :journal_id_1
```

which is correct. From the error I can see that when I append `delete()` to the query the join part of SQL statement gets lost and the database doesn't know how to find the `papers.journal_id` column obviously. What I don't understand is why does that happen?

This is the setup of my ORM objects

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    papers = db.relationship("UserPaper", backref=db.backref('users'), lazy='dynamic')

class Paper(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'papers'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(1024))
    journal_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('journals.id'))

class UserPaper(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'userpapers'

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
    paper_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('papers.id'), primary_key=True)
    paper = db.relationship("Paper", backref=db.backref('user_paper'))
    read_at = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    score = db.Column(db.Integer)

class Journal(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'journals'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), index = True, unique = True)
    papers = db.relationship('Paper', backref = 'journal', lazy = 'dynamic')
```

Comment: What's the SQLAlchemy version? What's the SQL db and version?

Comment: SQLAlchemy is 0.8.2, SQL db is MySQL 5.6.12

Comment: I have exactly the same problem - you did not find a solution to this yet ?

Comment: No sorry I didn't. I ended up using the very inefficient solution of creating the query, looping through the results and deleting them one by one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem with SQLALchemy 0.9 using MySQL 5.6. It looks like a bug/limitation. However, one better way to get arround (in comparison to creating the query, looping through the results and deleting them one by one) is to perform this task in two subsequent queries:

```
    paperQuery = db.session.query(Paper.id)\
                                    filter(Paper.journal_id == journal.id)


    baseQuery  = db.session.query(UserPaper)\
                                    .filter(UserPaper.paper_id.in_(paperQuery.subquery()))
                                    .filter(UserPaper.user_id == user.id).delete(synchronize_session='fetch')
```

It worked well for me, it should solve you issue too.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it as soon as I can and let you know if it worked for me.

Comment: Finally I had a chance to try your solution and it worked perfectly. Thanks!